# dispatching a redux reducer inside the async function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I have a redux slice, where I have

```
const initialState = { number = 0 }
```

and then regular reducer,

```
reducers: setNumber: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.number= action.payload;
    }
```

then i have a function `const handlePost = async () => { //some code; dispatch(setNumber(number+1)}`

but as I see it does not update number immediately because I use this number to refresh a component and it does not being refreshed.

What's the best way to handle it?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example